# API requests doesn't work on my computer but the other

Tags: rest, laravel, xampp

I have a very simple API created by using Laravel 5.2.22, when calling GET methods I am getting the error 404, calling DELETE method I am getting the error 405 (same thing using postman or curl). The point is that the same project works perfectly on another machine.

Is there anything that I have to configure in my Xampp to make this works? 
Could anybody help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you said, the cause can be in wrong web server configuration. You should point your web server to a `public` directory of Laravel project. For example, if you've installed Laravel in `C:/xampp/htdocs/` directory, you need to use these settings:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/public">
```

After that restart web server. Also, make sure `storage` directory has right permissions.

Do this, if you'll get similar error message, please turn on Debug and post full error message.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't pointing to the public directory. I was using in my request the url: http://localhost/project/api/v1/catalog/1 instead of http://localhost/project/public/api/v1/catalog/1
Thanks!!!